# List of tuples in String format to List of tuples Conversion

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples where tuple is in string format

```
data_list = ["('https://www.test.org/', 'testing', 'test1', 'test1')", "('https://testing2.com/', 'testing', 'test2', 'test2')"]
```

To convert this to list of tuples I am using the following code

```
for val in data_list:
    valx = ast.literal_eval(val)
```

But some time I will have the list of tuples with `Undefined` parameter like below.

```
["('https://www.test.org/', 'testing', Undefined, Undefined)", "('https://testing.com/', 'testing', Undefined, Undefined)"]
```

In this case using the above code will give the following error

```
flask    |     raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
flask    | ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7fab4d78ab80>
```

I am not sure how to handle this error. In the place of `Undefined`, a null string will be enough.

Comment: `valx = ast.literal_eval(val.replace("Undefined", "None"))` ?? (Regex replace might be better...)

Comment: FYI the proper deception of _"list of tuples where tuple is in string format"_ is _"list of string representations of tuples"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replace it with `None`? (In my example with eval instead of ast.literal_eval:

```py
data_list = ["('https://www.test.org/', 'testing', Undefined, 'test1')", "('https://testing2.com/', 'testing', 'test2', 'test2')"]

for val in data_list:
    val = val.replace('Undefined', 'None')
    valx = eval(val)
    print(valx)
```

You may want to use regex to differ between `Undefined` und `'Undefined'` (string)